# How to add a blurred drop shadow to a button?

Tags: android, gradient, blur, dropshadow

I need to add blurred drop shadow to my button:

[image]

I tried to create background with layer-list xml drawable, but it not looks like blur.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Drop Shadow Stack -->
    <item>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="45dp" />
            <padding
                android:bottom="2dp"
                android:left="1dp"
                android:right="1dp"
                android:top="1dp" />

            <stroke
                android:width="6dp"
                android:color="#007879E8" />

        </shape>
    </item>
    //////   10 more items
        <item>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="45dp" />
            <padding
                android:bottom="2dp"
                android:left="1dp"
                android:right="1dp"
                android:top="1dp" />

            <stroke
                android:width="6dp"
                android:color="#177879E8" />


        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Background -->
    <item>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="45dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@color/main_purple_text_color" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Also i tried to use background element behind button with blured png but it uses to many resources and i cannot create selector to change background on hover or click.

I need to have single background file for button and use selector to change blur and gradient on hover/click.
Any ideas how to achieve such effect with Android SDK ?

**UPDATE 1**

Thanks everybody for answers, but I'm not asking how to create gradient. I've already done this. I need to create blurred drop-shadow.

Comment: Were you able to do in a better way? thanks.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Well i found the solution: we need to create 9.png with blurred drop-shadow via this [generator](http://inloop.github.io/shadow4android/) and pass it to drawable layer-list that contain button background gradient:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/blurred_9_path_png" />
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
            <corners android:radius="45dp" />
            <gradient
                android:angle="45"
                android:endColor="@color/facebook_btn_fill_grad2"
                android:startColor="@color/facebook_btn_fill_grad1"
                android:type="linear" />
            <padding
                android:bottom="0dp"
                android:left="0dp"
                android:right="0dp"
                android:top="0dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

After that we can use such drawables with different 9.path blurred shadow to create selector.

Comment: what options did you put in the website?

Comment: Yea what options did u put on the website to create that?

Comment: I would also be interested to know what options you used on the site. And what if the size of the button changes, how to apply the shadow in this case?

Answer (score 5):

I add this as background drawable (grey drop shadow):

```
<!-- Drop Shadow Stack -->
<item>
    <shape>
        <padding
            android:bottom="1dp"
            android:left="1dp"
            android:right="1dp"
            android:top="1dp" />
        <solid android:color="#1f000000" />
        <corners android:radius="30dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <padding
            android:bottom="1dp"
            android:left="1dp"
            android:right="1dp"
            android:top="1dp" />
        <solid android:color="#2f000000" />
        <corners android:radius="30dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <padding
            android:bottom="1dp"
            android:left="1dp"
            android:right="1dp"
            android:top="1dp" />
        <solid android:color="#3f000000" />
        <corners android:radius="30dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- Background -->
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        <corners android:radius="30dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Ensures the height/width/padding of textview large enough to contains above shadow 3dp (1dp+1dp+1dp for all colors from #3f000000 until #1f000000).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by Graident

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<gradient 
    android:startColor="#6586F0"
    android:centerColor="#D6D6D6"
    android:endColor="#4B6CD6"
    android:angle="90"/>
<corners 
    android:radius="0dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did for my cardview and this works for me:

```
<item name="cardElevation">8dp</item>
<item name="cardUseCompatPadding">true</item>
```

Comment: If possible, can you please post the output as well.

Answer (score -2):

[image]

Create drawable **shadow.xml** file

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<solid android:color="#E3D5FC" />
<corners
    android:radius="20dp"/>
<padding
    android:bottom="1dp"
    android:left="1dp"
    android:right="1dp"
    android:top="1dp" >
</padding>
```

Create another drawable **background.xml** file

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/shadow" />
<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient
            android:angle="0"
            android:centerColor="#9E7CEF"
            android:endColor="#B070EB"
            android:startColor="#8989F4" />
        <corners android:radius="22dp" />
        <size android:height="40dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

and use this file in xml as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/img_save"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="BUTTON"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it Helps.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't looks blurred.

Comment: to add shadow like blur view you can add background image exact like effect.