# How to implement a rounded Button with gradient background and blurred shadow?

Tags: android, xml, button, material-design, shadow

I am trying to achieve something like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SseaB.png

For default Button/AppCompatButton, i had tried to apply gradient background with rounded corners that was predefined in xml drawable. But how to implement shadow with blur?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47674828/how-to-add-a-blurred-drop-shadow-to-a-button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a blurred drop shadow to a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47674828/how-to-add-a-blurred-drop-shadow-to-a-button)

Answer (score 0):

**Create a drawable class *bg_theme_round_layer_shadow***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <!-- Drop Shadow Stack -->
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#02AAAAAA" />
            <corners android:radius="46.5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#05AAAAAA" />
            <corners android:radius="46dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#0FAAAAAA" />
            <corners android:radius="45.5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#1CAAAAAA" />
            <corners android:radius="44.5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#24AAAAAA" />
            <corners android:radius="43.5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Background -->
    <item>
        <shape>
            <!--<solid android:color="@color/theme_color" />-->
            <gradient android:endColor="@color/gradient_normal_end" android:startColor="@color/gradient_normal_start"/>

            <corners android:radius="43dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**Put these colors in your color file**

```
<color name="gradient_normal_start">#e85d7b</color>
<color name="gradient_normal_end">#efa645</color>
```