# Android - shadow effect below rectangle

Tags: android, gradient, shadow

I would like to create a shadow effect as in picture

[image]

Tried multiple options saw in stack overflow. None of them worked.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to approach this is by creating any type of view and give it a background designed as black fill with the gradient property, like explained here:

[How to add a blurred drop shadow to a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47674828/how-to-add-a-blurred-drop-shadow-to-a-button)

And then place this view on top of the original image, overlapping it.