# Blurr border of component in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I need to reproduce [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnR6x.png).

I've made the code for the blue rectangle so far but I can't find a way to add that white blurr around the rectangle.

Does anyone know how to do it?

It's easy in all languages except Kotlin...

Comment: It would not be a feature of the programming language, but of whatever platform you are working with.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a blurred drop shadow to a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47674828/how-to-add-a-blurred-drop-shadow-to-a-button)

Comment: Thank you @PhilipDukhov, it is indeed the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make use of third party libraries. Such designs patterns are called neumorphisms . These can be achieved easily using these  library :

1. Fornewid-Neumorphism

> https://github.com/fornewid/neumorphism

2. Synth-CRED

> https://github.com/CRED-CLUB/synth-android

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help but this is not what I'm looking for. It is rather impressive though.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers.
I've finally found **Jetpack Compose** (don't know why I didn't see it sooner) and I will be using that going forward.
It seems to be the better way of building an app's UI in Kotlin.